# Dropdown requires multiple clicks to open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created multiple drop downs through an iteration with javascript. It works fine, except there is a point where a user has to click twice to get the drop down to work.

This happens when a user clicks on a dropdown, doesn't click to close it, goes to click on another drop down which then closes the first dropdown, but then if they go to click on the first dropdown again, it takes two clicks to open.

Is there a way to only click once in this situation?
(I've only pasted the relevant code for the dropdown html)

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.dropbtn').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).parent(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-content').removeClass('show-dropdown');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.dropdown-content').removeClass('show-dropdown');
      $(this).parent(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-content').addClass('show-dropdown');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.show-dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Options <span>▼</span></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <span> drop down stuff </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you reset the dropdown on any click made outside dropdown menu?

```
  $('body').click(function() {
   // [TODO] add if statement to see if dropdown is active?...
   $(this).parent(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-content').removeClass('show-dropdown');
   $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What Iglo said seems like the correct solution, although without stopping event propagation, his solution will instantly close the popup when it opens. You would need to prevent event propagation for that to work, I think.

My suggested solution has an added layer:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {

    var multi_select = $(".multi-select-menu");
    if (multi_select.is(":visible")) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest('.multi-select-menu').length) {
            if (!isOpeningMultiSelect) {
                $('.multi-select-menu').slideUp(MULTI_SELECT_SLIDE_TIME);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

I have a custom set of dropdowns that do not use input tags at all.

You can see the full code here, as it sounds like I do almost the exact same thing you do. https://dogonnet.us/Me

That is the only example of the dropdown visible without registering, but you can feel free to register with a fake email. The website is in development. And once you do, you can see a massive ton of them on this page: https://dogonnet.us/Dog

This page shows the whole process of clicking outside a dropdown to close another, along with multi-select in the same drop down.

(Inspect the DOM, the code for this drop down logic is in MultiSelect.js)